# note taking app : editing notes and updating to local storage (replacing)

Tags: javascript

I'm on a venture of creating a note taking app. At the moment, I can add a note, save it to local storage and display it, but id like to be able to edit and update back into the local storage.
Notes are captured in a 'popup' window and then displayed into the page. Have tried a series of things but with no success.

I understand that im using a constructor/ array and understand how to update arrays lasts and first indexes, but when it comes to input it seems to be more complicated. Ill appreciate any help.

```js
const noteListDiv = document.querySelector(".note-list");
let noteID = 1;

function Note(id, title, content) {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.content = content;

}

function eventListeners() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", displayNotes);
  document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", addNewNote);
  // document.querySelector(".edit").addEventListener("click", updateNote); 


  noteListDiv.addEventListener("dblclick", deleteNote);

  //    document.querySelector(".delete-all-btn").addEventListener("click", deleteAllNotes);

}


function getDataFromStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("notes") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) : [];

}

function createNote(noteItem) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("note-item");
  div.setAttribute("data-id", noteItem.id);
  div.innerHTML = `
          <h3 contenteditable = "true" class="card-title-area">${noteItem.title}</h3><br>

          <p contenteditable = "true"  class="card-note-area">${noteItem.content}</p><br>
          <div id="display-value"></div>
          <button type = "button" class = "btn delete-note-btn">
          <span><i class = "fas fa-trash"></i></span>
          Delete
          </buttton>
          <button type = "button"  class="btn edit">
          <span><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span>
          Edit
          </button> 
    `;
  noteListDiv.appendChild(div);
}
eventListeners();

function addNewNote() {
  const noteTitle = document.getElementById("title-inb");
  const noteContent = document.getElementById("note-inb");


  if (validateInput(noteTitle, noteContent)) {
    let notes = getDataFromStorage();

    let noteItem = new Note(noteID, noteTitle.value, noteContent.value);
    noteID++;
    notes.push(noteItem);
    createNote(noteItem);

    // saving in the local storage 

    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
    noteTitle.value = "";
    noteContent.value = "";


  }

}

function updateNote() {

  const cardNote = document.querySelectorAll(".card-note-area").value
  const cardTitle = document.querySelectorAll(".card-title-area").value


  if (validateInput(cardNote, cardTitle)) {
    let notes = getDataFromStorage();

    let noteItem = new Note(noteID, cardNote.value, cardTitle.value);
    noteID++;
    notes.push(noteItem);


    // saving in the local storage 

    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
    cardTitle.value = "";
    cardNote.value = "";


  }
}


function validateInput(title, content) {
  if (title.value !== "" && content.value !== "") {
    return true;
  } else {
    if (title.value === "") title.classList.add("warning");
    if (content.value === "") content.classList.add("warning");
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    title.classList.remove("warning");
    content.classList.remove("warning");

  }, 1600);
}


function displayNotes() {
  let notes = getDataFromStorage();
  if (notes.length > 0) {
    noteID = notes[notes.length - 1].id;
    noteID++;
  } else {
    noteID = 1;
  }
  notes.forEach(item => {
    createNote(item);
  });
}


// delete a note 
function deleteNote(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete-note-btn")) {

    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    let divID = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id;
    let notes = getDataFromStorage();
    let newNotesList = notes.filter(item => {
      return item.id !== parseInt(divID);
    });
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(newNotesList));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="note-list">
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? Is it in the saving, or updating, or elsewhere?

Comment: I can add, save it to local storage and display, all I like to do now is edit saved note and replace the old note withe the new one into local storage/array as well.

Comment: Can you show us the JSON object of a note.

Comment: ```function Note(id, title, content) {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.content = content;

}```

Let me know if haven't understood correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `updateNote` function.
Modified the existing code to make the functionality work.

```js
function updateNote() {

  const cardNote = document.querySelectorAll(".card-note-area").value
  const cardTitle = document.querySelectorAll(".card-title-area").value

  // to update a note, you need to be able to reference it somehow.
  // since this note already exists, we want to use the id it has (not create a new one).
  //
  // now i'm not sure how the data flow is structured in this project 
  // (idk if this is the correct way here to retrieve the id of the note). 
  // Point is, you wanna extract that note's existing id somehow.
  const id = document.querySelectorAll('.note-item').getAttribute('data-id');


  if (validateInput(cardNote, cardTitle)) {
    const oldNotes = getDataFromStorage();

    const newNoteItem = new Note(id, cardNote.value, cardTitle.value);
    
    // We're updating a note, not creating one, so no need to increment here
    // noteID++;

    // we remove the old note from the array
    const newNotes = oldNotes.filter(note => note.id !== id);

    // we now push our note with new data (but the same old id) in the array
    // take care of saving the new array, not the old one.
    newNotes.push(newNoteItem);

    // saving in the local storage 
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(newNotes));
    cardTitle.value = "";
    cardNote.value = "";


  }
}
```

PS: Haven't tested this. And not concerned with fixing style or best practices or anything, just modifying what is there.

Also: This would be easier if you used a hashmap/dictionary instead of an array for your notes.

Then you could do something like: `notesMap[id] = /* your note */`, when creating or updating, and `delete notesMap[id]` when deleting.

Easier (less likely to get weird bugs), but also faster (all in constant time). The right tool for the right job.

Hope this helps!